# pac4j raises "State cannot be determined" when trying to get keycloakOidcProfile after OIDC callback and Keycloak provider

Tags: keycloak, spring-webflux, pac4j

I am trying to implement `pac4j` `openid` with keycloak in Spring webflux project with `JAVA 19` and `spring boot 3.0.3`.
I am also facing same issue while fetching `KeycloakOidcProfile` after authentication is done in keycloak.

I notice that when it redirect to keycloak login page it sets SESSION cookie and at the end when callback url comes it get that SESSION cookie. cookie is not getting changed than also getting this same error.

```
public Mono<keycloakOidcProfile> getUserProfile(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return Mono.just(serverRequest)
                .flatMap(serverRequest1 -> {
                    if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(serverRequest1.queryParams().get("code"))) {
                        //getting code from url
                        System.out.println(serverRequest1.queryParam("code").get());
                    }
                    final WebContext context = new SpringWebfluxWebContext(serverRequest1.exchange());
                    final SessionStore sessionStore = new SpringWebfluxSessionStore(serverRequest1.exchange());
                    final ProfileManager profileManager = new ProfileManager(context,sessionStore);
                    
                    Optional<Credentials> credentials = config.getClients().findClient("KeycloakOidcClient").get().getCredentials(context,sessionStore);
                    Optional<UserProfile> userProfile = config.getClients().findClient("KeycloakOidcClient").get().getUserProfile(credentials.get(),context,sessionStore);
                    KeycloakOidcProfile keycloakOidcProfile = (KeycloakOidcProfile) userProfile.get();

                    System.out.println(keycloakOidcProfile.getAccessToken());

                    return keycloakOidcProfile;
                });
}
```

I am getting `"Referrer-policy"` variable as `"no-referrer"` in header from keycloak. Is this cause the problem?
could you please guide me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same SESSION cookie before and after the successful login at Keycloak, it should work. Generally, this kind of problem comes from an unwanted renewed/lost session.

Can you turn on `DEBUG` logs on the `org.pac4j.springframework.context.SpringWebfluxSessionStore` class (the session store) to see what's going on? Thx